# HtmlRouteProvider not found error

Tags: modal-dialogs

I've just started using the [Modal](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_page) module version  4.1.15 and haven't made any changes to the file structure, now after clearing the cache I get this error: 
`Error: Class 'Drupal\modal_page\Entity\RouteProvider\ModalHtmlRouteProvider' not found in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->createHandlerInstance() (line 272 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php)`

Is there a new class I need to create to serve a route to the function, or is this an easy fix?

Comment: Can you confirm the module is actually enabled?

Comment: It does allow itself to be enabled, but gives that same error upon enabling it.

Comment: You don't need to create classes for the module to work. If the module is using a wrong class for an entity handler, that's a bug with the module.

Comment: Actually, the [`Drupal\modal_page\Entity\RouteProvider\ModalHtmlRouteProvider`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/modal_page/-/blob/4.1.15/src/Entity/RouteProvider/ModalHtmlRouteProvider.php) exists and it's used by the [`Modal`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/modal_page/-/blob/4.1.15/src/Entity/Modal.php) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the RouteProvider folder containing the class I needed was deleted somehow, dropping it back in and clearing the cache fixed the issue.